# Ruby on Rails : How to group list of names based on the initial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of names in array, example:

```
['John', 'Smith', 'Doe', 'Lee', 'Jack']
```

I want it to be grouped like this:

```
['Doe']
['Jack', 'John']
['Lee']
['Smith']
```

How do I do that with ruby on rails?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enumerable's [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) is your friend:

```
names = ['John', 'Smith', 'Doe', 'Lee', 'Jack']
names.group_by{ |n| n[0] } 
# => {"J"=>["John", "Jack"], "S"=>["Smith"], "D"=>["Doe"], "L"=>["Lee"]}
names.group_by{ |n| n[0] }.values 
# => [["John", "Jack"], ["Smith"], ["Doe"], ["Lee"]]
```

From the documentation:

> Groups the collection by result of the block. Returns a hash where the keys are the evaluated result from the block and the values are arrays of elements in the collection that correspond to the key.

If you want to order them alphabetically, simply sort the initial array before using `group_by`. Because Ruby maintains the insertion order of a hash, the resulting values for the hash will be in order too:

```
names.sort.group_by{ |n| n[0] }.values 
# => [["Doe"], ["Jack", "John"], ["Lee"], ["Smith"]]
```

Comment: Yes, `group_by(&:chr)` would work, except in Ruby < 1.9 unless the user is running something that implements the symbol to proc method.

Comment: since the question is tagged *rails* I'd write `names.group_by(&:first).values.sort`.

Comment: More precisely, `Symbol#to_proc` first appeared in the core lib in 1.8.7. `group_by` itself wasn't available until 1.8.7, so the answer must be confined to >= 1.8.7. And @AJcodez's suggestion to use `String#chr` only works with >= 1.9.1. Also, you should use `n[0,1]` in the `group_by` block so it also works with 1.8.7.

Comment: Hm, you might as well confine your answer to >= 1.9 because of the bit about `Hash` maintaining insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to use the chunk method:

```
names = ['John', 'Smith', 'Doe', 'Lee', 'Jack']
p names.sort.chunk(&:chr).map(&:last) #=> [["Doe"], ["Jack", "John"], ["Lee"], ["Smith"]]
```